# How to parse an XML sitemap using python scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the following sitemap using scrapy: https://comercialtrevino.com/sitemap/sitemaprssatom_products.xml

At first I would like to use the scrapy shell and then I'll write a spider to extract all the url's I'm interested in.

I tried both:

```
scrapy shell "https://comercialtrevino.com/sitemap/sitemaprssatom_products.xml"

scrapy shell -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False "https://comercialtrevino.com/sitemap/sitemaprssatom_products.xml"
```

And then I tried all of this:

```
response.css("body")
response.css("entry")
response.css("url")
response.css("span.html-tag")
response.css("title")
response.xpath("//entry")
response.xpath("//loc")
response.xpath("//url")
response.xpath("//span")
response.xpath("//title")
```

And every output is an empty array!

the sitemap as I open it on the browser has a lot of "entry" tags, on the inspector tool I saw the span.html-tag element and on the view(response) method I saw the "loc" tags. I don't even know which structure to target but none of them work :(

I also wrote a spider:

```html
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from scrapy.item import Item

class Trevi_Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'trevi'
    start_urls = ["https://comercialtrevino.com/sitemap/sitemaprssatom_products.xml",]
    iterator = 'iternodes'
    namespaces = ['g', "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"]
    #itertag = "g:link"
    itertag = 'entry'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        self.log('oiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii ----------------> ', node, self.itertag)
        self.logger.info(f"Hi this is a {self.itertag} node!: {''.join(node.getall())}")

        item = Item()
        #item["src"] = node.xpath("/text()").get()
        item["src"] = node.xpath("//g:link/text()").get()
        print('oiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii ------------------>', item)
        return item
```

But I can't even see the prints or logs to the console.

Comment: You could just use `SitemapSpider`.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed!

I end up using the spider within a scrapy project

I corrected a mistake: the namespace had to be an array of tuples; I had forgotten the parenthesis

I also defined the TreviSpiderItem class in the items.py file

the spider ended up like this:

```html
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
#from scrapy.item import Item
from trevi_spider.items import TreviSpiderItem

class Trevi_Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'trevi'
    start_urls = ["https://comercialtrevino.com/sitemap/sitemaprssatom_products.xml",]
    iterator = 'iternodes'
    namespaces = [('g', "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")]
    #itertag = "g:link"
    itertag = 'entry'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        #self.log(f'oiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii ---------------->  {node} ---------------------> {self.itertag}')
        #self.logger.info(f"Hi this is a {self.itertag} node!: {''.join(node.getall())}")

        item = TreviSpiderItem()
        #item["src"] = node.xpath("/text()").get()
        #item["src"] = node.xpath("//g:link/text()").get()
        item["src"] = node.xpath("//g:link/text()").get()
        #print('oiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii ------------------>', item)
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Which nodes are interesting for you?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib

url = "https://comercialtrevino.com/sitemap/sitemaprssatom_products.xml"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data= response.read()
tree = ET.fromstring(data)

for node in tree.iter():
    # do you parsing here.
    print(node.tag, node.text)
```